# Decimal and Real values are rendered with different decimal point symbols in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I run this query in SSMS:

```
select convert(decimal(18,2),1.1), convert(real,1.1)
```

I will get two different decimal points, "1.10" and "1,1".

With my current locale/regional settings, I would expect `,` to be used as decimal point for both cases.

Why is SQL Server (or SQL Server Management Studio?) formatting decimals and real numbers in a different way?
Is there any way things can be configures to get this right?

Of course, in my code, I get the correct datatypes and can display the correct decimal point, but when running a select on tables with real and decimal datatypes, I get this mixed use of decimal points, so It's kinda tedious to paste into Excel.
In earlier versions of SSMS/query analyzer this was not a problem, but now it is?

Comment: Just don't use parsing in the database itself. Use the correct field types and pass numbers and dates as strongly-typed parameters.

Comment: I'm not parsing, I run a query, and expect the output to be compatible with other software, so pasting the result into Excel for instance should work, without using formatting functions on the result.

Comment: There is no "localized decimal point" in the numerical values themselves, they are just binary values. Numeric literals always use `.`. Localization applies ONLY when you format a number as a string for display, parse a user-supplied string or parse a text file

Comment: So why is the same query displaying two different values when I run it in SSMS? one column return . and the other returns ,?
The query here is to simplify the question, insstead of creating an table with an real and an decimal column which gives the same excact result.

Comment: There is no formatting and no localization involved, no `.` and no `,`. The numbers are binary values. The *client* application reads and formats it for display. Excel does NOT make any conversions to the actual values. If you store the Excel sheet, unzip it and check the XML files , you'll see it containst only `.` for decimals.

Comment: There are no different values. The *CLIENT* displays the values. Excel will display `10.345` in the US and `10,345` in Europe for the same value, based on the user's locale settings. SSMS is just a client. In fact, you can change how such things *appear* in an application by changing its locale.

Comment: I know ssms is an client, and that's the issue, how can you get ssms to do the same for all float datatypes?

Comment: Try the `COLLATE` function.

Comment: It does already. That's the point. The value is exactly the same and you *don't* have to change anything. SSMS may choose to use the same display format that is used for literals, and that's a very good idea. Imagine typing `10.3` in a query but reading `10,3` in a grid. If you copied that grid value to your query, you'd get 103 or 10300 instead of 10.3.

Comment: @JacobH why? There is no collation or localization problem. SSMS, a DBA client tool, uses the same format as that used for literals. Maybe there's a setting in options to change this, but it shouldn't be used. Formatting numbers in a localized way is available through [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: @neslekkiM if you want numbers to be formatted in a certain way, use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) with the locale you want, eg `select format(1.1,'n2','fr-FR')`

Comment: I wish you could actually run the query and observe that it gives you two columns..

Comment: You say you got different results in older SMSS versions? Which versions did/do you use?

Comment: @neslekkiM if you mean that decimals and floats use a different decimal point, you should reformat the question. It's not obvious *at all* that this is the question. It doesn't change the fact that the data doesn't change, but it  *is* a discrepancy

Comment: I tried to paste a image there to show it better, but the point is that the query has two columns, one is decimal and one is real, bot which is floatingpoint values, and should be handled the same, as the regionalsettings/locale is set. But one columns is returned with . and the other column is returned with , in the same query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a documented bug.

See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/458416/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-doesnt-get-os-regional-setting) for the original bug report, and [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/636074/some-datatypes-doesnt-honor-localization) for the follow up. It doesn't look like MS is going to fix this (soon).

I am surprised you see a difference between SSMS versions though.

Comment: I might remember wrong, or I have used an locale before that gave same result, everyother time I reinstall my computer/install office, I get different setup :), looking at sqlserver 2000 this worked fine, but the bug is in ssms 2008 also.

Comment: Apparently, if you use US settings, you would get the expected results. So I would imagine that being the issue.